# Static Hardware Identifiers on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We're trying to set up a Windows Continuous Integration server in the cloud that has software with a particularly difficult licensing scheme (a certain embedded software compiler). This compiler either lets the user run with a dongle, or node locks the software to run on a specific set of hardware. Seeing as how we can't exactly ship off a dongle to Amazon to plug in to our machine for us, we want to use the node locked licensing scheme with this software.

However, in order for this license to remain valid, my EC2 instance needs to have a set of "static" hardware IDs. We don't actually know which hardware IDs this software will look for (and they won't tell us), but I'd like to know which hardware IDs I should expect to change with instance restarts, and which hardware IDs, if any, I can lock down through proper configuration of my EC2 instance.

For example, I already know that I can lock down the MAC address of the Network Interface using Amazon's Elastic Network Interface (ENI). Is there any other configuration I can do, or need to do, in order to get a set of static hardware IDs?

Comment: You should look at [dedicated hosts](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/dedicated-hosts/) to see if it addresses the licensing requirements of your application.

Comment: You should tell the vendor that you are using Amazon EC2 and that they should provide details on how to run their software on that platform, otherwise you will refuse to buy their software. That should kick them into action. (And if it doesn't, it's probably not a software company with whom you want to work long-term.)

Comment: @MattHouser We did consider those. But that adds a tremendous amount of monthly expense to this.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein We tried that approach with them. While they understood our plight, the vendor claimed they don't have enough embedded customers that actually have enough discipline to do continuous integration.  This does, obviously, hurt their credibility and makes us consider other compilers for the future.